# Override a method using a category, when that method was already defined in a category

Tags: objective-c, methods, overriding, objective-c-category

I have the following code that I'm using.

```
@interface SomeDudesSuperClass : NSObject {

}

@end

@interface SomeDudesSuperClass (Category_code_which_others_are_restricted_from_touching)

- (void)SomeDudesMethod;

@end
```

Now this below is my code

```
@interface SomeDudesSuperClass (A_Category_To_Override_A_Method_in_his_category) {

- (void)SomeDudesMethod;

}

@end
```

I am not allowed to touch his code. If I just write up another category, which method will be called? And how can I call my category method instead of his?

Comment: It's a bad idea to override methods using categories. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: @rmaddy ok.. in a case such as mine.. are there any possible work arounds? I cant touch his code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rmaddy said, what you're doing is not a good idea and will result in undefined behavior. You shouldn't try to override methods in a category. If you absolutely can't touch the existing code you can reasonably do one of 2 things.

1. Subclass `SomeDudesSuperClass` and override the method there.
2. Use method swizzling to swap the method implementation with your custom one instead of overriding. This also gives you the option of implementing this like a proper override and call the original implementation inside your custom method if you need to.

[This article by Mike Ash has a very nice explanation of this](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html).

Comment: swizzling it is. i had thoughts about it but wasnt sure

Comment: One thing, when you say Override his class, you mean a subclass right?

Comment: Oops, I sure do! Will edit my answer.